# Ajax can not pass parameter to WebMethod in IE 10 ONLY - Missing value for parameter: \u0027recordID\u0027

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, internet-explorer-10, webmethod

I searched again and again but no hope. And I started to think that this is a IE 10 bug. Because the code below worked fine for Chrome, Firefox, IE 7 8 9, and so on.

I got this error

```
    GetDataFromWebMethod(): {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027recordID\u0027.","StackTrace":" 
    at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n 
    at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams
    (Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n 
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n 
        at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

when I tried to call an ASP.NET WebMethod with a parameter like this:

```
var dataToSend = '{"recordID":"' + id + '"}';
var URLDataForm = 'FundsMain.aspx/Get';
oriEntity = GetDataFromWebMethod(URLDataForm, dataToSend);
```

with a function like this

```
function GetDataFromWebMethod(webMethodUrl, dataToSend) {
    if (webMethodUrl == '' || webMethodUrl === undefined) return null;

    var data;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataToSend,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: webMethodUrl,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (responseTxt) {
            data = $.parseJSON(responseTxt.d.ResponseData);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            showMessageBox("error", "Error", "GetDataFromWebMethod(): " + err.responseText);
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static AjaxResponse Get(int recordID)
{
      // remove for brevity
}
```

with below debugging data:

```
 - in Firefox: dataToSend "{"recordID":"1625"}" 
 - in IE <10:  dataToSend "{\"recordID\":\"1625\"}" String
 - in Chrome:  dataToSend:"{"recordID":"1625"}"
 - in IE 10:   dataToSend "{\"recordID\":\"1625\"}" String   **(same as IE <10 !)**
```

Anyone have any idea about this? Or I guess I missed something?
Thank for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seem to be an IE 10 bug. Thanks for help @Damith :)

Comment: If you add more details about your findings it would be helpful for others who may have the same issue in future. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Currently, the bug is still remained in my project. I set it to pending. Thanks for suggestion. If I have it, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

since the web method parameter is `int`, try with below

```
var dataToSend = '{"recordID":' + id + '}';
```

instead of

```
var dataToSend = '{"recordID":"' + id + '"}';
```

Comment: I tried with var dataToSend = '{"recordID":' + id + '}'; but no luck. Same error happened.

Answer (score 0):

Add meta tag as

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

And then use

```
var dataToSend = '{"recordID":' + id + '}';
```

Instead of

```
var dataToSend = '{"recordID":"' + id + '"}';
```

Hope this work fine on IE 10